# Measurement conversion cm to inch

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have one column full of height data like "30 to 90 cm" and I'd like to know if there's a formula that can convert it to inches, round it off, and also retain the format. For example, the output would be: 12 to 35 inches, all without having to manually update the cell one by one.

Is there a formula for this? Anyone can help?

I tried to search but haven't found a way. Maybe this is impossible?

Answer (score 1):

You may try:

```
=map(A2:A,lambda(z,if(z="",,let(Σ,split(substitute(z,"cm","inches")," "),join(" ",index(if(isnumber(Σ),round(convert(Σ,"cm","in")),Σ)))))))
```

[image]